# How to use cURL in magento 1.9 module

Tags: php, api, curl, magento-1.9

I've developed a module, at the moment only some function and get/post from to Database , the front I have it already done.
I want to add a class (cURL) to call 3rd party api, but I don't know how can I to implement that. It should be in controllers(IndexController?) or Model folder as new file? and if I have to add some details in config.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no restriction to use the curl in a particular file. It depends on your module functionality and parameters. The most effective effort to use curl in indexcontroller. Use can create a function and initiate them.

Example like:

```
  <?php

    $curl = new Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl();
    $curl->setConfig(array(
           'timeout'   => 15    //Timeout in no of seconds
    ));
    $feed_url = "http://feeds.feedburner.com/magento";
    $curl->write(Zend_Http_Client::GET, $feed_url, '1.0');
    $data = $curl->read();
    if ($data === false) {
       return false;
    }
    $data = preg_split('/^r?$/m', $data, 2);
    $data = trim($data[1]);
    $curl->close();

    try {
      $xml  = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
     //Parse the XML FEED and output the data
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
       echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: it's a bit more clear, but I should use some magento methods? I've edited my post and add the class curl I've used before in shopify, prestashop and opencart but isn't clear to me yet use it in magento. Thanks alot for your comments.

Comment: I've implemented in the controller and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to add ur cURl in helper class and call that helper method from controller.
No need to add any details in config.xml .Simply define your helper class in config.xml and add the cURL data in a helper function